# SHA256 Behave Differently In c#

Tags: c#, sha256

I need to pass a SHA256 hash to some 3rd party API. They have even provided a sample in JS which works fine and the results is matched with online SHA256 generator like this one:

- https://codebeautify.org/sha256-hash-generator

But the problem occurs when I use C# to generate the SHA256 hash.

I've matched almost everything like input, encoding; etc.
But I'm not exactly sure  what the issue actually.

Please check the input which behave differently below

### Input

```
{
  "correlation_identifier": "Payee Validation",
  "context": "PAYM",
  "creditor_account": "23124812341",
  "creditor_name": "NARUMATT",
  "uetr": "3c9e595f-07d8-4f56-ae80-8edbb7683d59",
  "creditor_agent": {
    "bicfi": "BSALSVSS"
  }
}
```

### Online Results

a425b580c44e2c3ba6ce213529818feea5bd7ccfd76ccd02171c87ff1e53c8ee

### C# Results

b192e9203176649de967fa4cbe9e513a77fc29797981ea1ce93e6e07e5dd94e3

### c# Code

```
       string inputString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Input()
            {
                correlation_identifier = "Payee Validation",
                context = "PAYM",
                creditor_account = "23124812341",
                creditor_name = "NARUMATT",
                uetr = "3c9e595f-07d8-4f56-ae80-8edbb7683d59",
                creditor_agent = new CreditorAgent()
                {
                    bicfi = "BSALSVSS"
                }

            }, Formatting.Indented);

       string base64Hash = GenerateSha256(inputString);
       static string GenerateSha256(string inputString)
            {
    
                var hash = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                using (SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create())
                {
                    byte[] hashBytes = sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString));
    
                    foreach (byte theByte in hashBytes)
                    {
                        hash.Append(theByte.ToString("x2"));
                    }
    
                }
                return hash.ToString();
            }
```

### JS Sample

```
var CryptoJS = require('crypto-js')
var reqBodyUtf8 = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(pm.request.body.raw);
var reqBodyDigest = CryptoJS.SHA256(reqBodyUtf8).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

Comment: Please show the js code sample

Comment: @DarkBee it's in the question below Input heading

Comment: Hashing doesn't behave differently in C#. In all the duplicate questions (and there are several) the *content* wasn't the same. Hashing treats whitespace the same as Spaces, indentation and newlines matter. What is the *exact* string you used in the C# code? I bet it's not what's posted here

Comment: it's exactly the same , i am reading it from text file

Comment: Are you using the hash as an API signature? API signatures are generated from the unindented content

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal `i am reading it from text file` all the more reason to assume it's *NOT* the same, because *newlines* will be different, indenting may use tabs or whitespace. *Remove* whitespace before calculating the hash

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal in any case, C# doesn't behave differently. You need to find why *your content* is different

Comment: What does `pm.request.body.raw` contain? What do you see when you print that to the console? Is it a string? An object? Does it contain whitespace?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos hey it's the same with whitespaces & intended . i have copy the same text in file

Comment: Start with a simple string, e.g. `abc` and your function will match the website you linked. So there is definitely something wrong with how you are reading that file.

Comment: No repro. When I use the question's JSON string in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tvSKHz) I get the exact same hash as the "online" converter: `a425b580c44e2c3ba6ce213529818feea5bd7ccfd76ccd02171c87ff1e53c8ee`

Comment: ... which suggests it may very well be a matter of line breaks.

Comment: hi guys i have update a question . to ignore file confusion i am now serializing the object and i am getting the same result. P.S i have try the serialize input too on online & it's different

Comment: i am not sure exactly what's happening because i just copy my whole code & its return different result as compare to my machine . 
result : a425b580c44e2c3ba6ce213529818feea5bd7ccfd76ccd02171c87ff1e53c8ee
https://dotnetfiddle.net/6xcdEJ

Comment: same code on my machine & it's returning : b192e9203176649de967fa4cbe9e513a77fc29797981ea1ce93e6e07e5dd94e3

Comment: Same code but different data. We already explained what's going on. The newlines and spaces are different. On Windows machines a newline is two characters `\r\n` while on Linux it's one `\n`. If you copy the string you posted here into your code instead of loading it from a file you'll see the hashes are identical

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks . this is exactly the issue \r\n and \n . so on fiddler they are using linux so that's why it's working fine may be ? because i just copy the whole code from fiddler